# how to get cloudinary url of uploded video using node js ???

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I have uploaded a mp4 file using node.js on my cloudinary account.But I am not able to get its url using public_id ? I have used

`cloudinary.video("public_Id")` as mentioned in documentation ,but it is returning me a video tag.I just want to get a video url by its public id. Please help.Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `cloudinary.url()` method -

```
cloudinary.url("video.mp4", {resource_type: "video"})
```

It will generate the URL for accessing the uploaded video.

For more information - 
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm

Comment: Thanks #Maor.G it works fine. One more question It is returning me a http url.Can i also get a rtsp or rtmp url from cloudinary ?